# Beans are not available from HandlerValidator

Tags: java, spring, javabeans, chain

The beans A, B are not redefined in this chain (null value). I need these beans for processing. In other class, everything is OK (the beans are defined in the configuration with the @Bean annotation).
Tell me, please, is it possible to add something like embedding to xml? How is this possible to implement? What solutions can there be?
Thank you in advance.

```
public class HandlerValidator implements SOAPHandler<SOAPMessageContext> {
    
        @Autowired
        A a;
    
        @Autowired
        B b;
    
        @Override
        public Set<QName> getHeaders() {
            return null;
        }
    
        @Override
        public boolean handleMessage(SOAPMessageContext context) {        
            return true;
        }
    
        @Override
        public boolean handleFault(SOAPMessageContext context) {
            return false;
        }
    
        @Override
        public void close(MessageContext context) {
    
        }
    }
```

and xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<handler-chains xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
                xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/javaee_web_services_metadata_handler_2_0.xsd">
    <handler-chain>
        <handler>
            <handler-class>/.../.validator.HandlerValidator</handler-class>
        </handler>
    </handler-chain>
</handler-chains>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is HandlerValidator is not being scanned by spring for autowiring to happen, try to define this handler validator as bean by adding annnotations like @component so that autowiring happens or define this handler validator as spring bean too .

Comment: I marked the class with this annotation, put breakpoints (debugger) on setters annotated as @Autowired. When loading a class, it enters these setters, and not empty instances come, but filled ones. But when the class starts "accepting messages", the links suddenly turn out to be empty.